# Wissenschaftliche Arbeit – Schreibweise von Akronymen

Tags: word-usage, abbreviation

Tauchen in einer wissenschaftlichen Arbeit Akronyme auf, so ist es üblich diese einmal zu erläutern und von dann an fortlaufend nur noch das Akronym zu verwenden. Ich frage mich ob es eine korrekte Schreibweise dafür gibt.

**Ein Beispiel:**

Wenn in einem Satz das Akronym BMW vorkommt.

Nun möchte ich das Akronym bekannt machen.

Schreibe ich:

> BMW (Bayerische Motoren Werke)

oder:

> die Bayerischen Motoren Werke (BMW)

Meine Frage also ist: Wird das Akronym oder die Bedeutung in Klammern gesetzt?

Comment: Witzig, dass das Deppenleerzeichen Teil des offiziellen Namens ist.

Comment: BMW ist wirklich ein sehr schlechtes Beispiel, weil es so bekannt ist, dass es nicht erklärt werden muss (oder auch ohne Erklärung verstanden wird), wie auch zum Beispiel GmbH oder PC. Ein besseres Beispiel wäre »die Ludwig-Maximilians-Universität München (LMU)«, und da hast du auch gleich deine Antwort ;)

Comment: Das stimmt allerdings!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Für Akronyme gilt grundsätzlich das Gleiche wie für andere Abkürzungen auch.
Sofern das Dokument kein spezielles Abkürzungsverzeichnis enthält, soll üblicherweise beim ersten Auftreten einer Abkürzung die vollständige Benennung und dahinter in Klammern die Abkürzung angegeben werden.

> Polytetrafluorethylen (PTFE)

Diese Schreibweise ist beispielsweise für DIN- und ISO-Normen ausdrücklich vorgeschrieben.

Bei den Vorgaben zur Gestaltung von Dokumenten gibt es allerdings manchmal eigenwillige Kreationen, die gelegentlich sogar allgemein übliche Regeln ignorieren. Es sollte also nicht überraschen, wenn die betreffende Organisationseinheit (Universität, Fachbereich o. Ä.) zu der Schreibweise von Abkürzungen eigene Vorgaben macht.

Answer (score 2):

Ich kann dir mal eben schildern, wie ich die Problematik bislang in meinen Haus- und Facharbeiten bearbeitet habe.
Je nachdem, wie etabliert ein Akronym ist, kann es entweder in Klammern erklärt werden oder in Klammern das erste Mal als Akronym erscheinen.

Bei deinem Beispiel von BMW wäre es völlig in Ordnung, wenn du die erste Variante benutzt.

> die BMW (Bayerischen Motoren Werke)

Da BMW in der Gesellschaft deutlich etabliert ist.
Ähnlich ist es mit Akronymen wie DNA, RNA, MS, ALS, HIV im biologischen Bereich. Bei Akronymen, die weniger etabliert sind, ist es hilfreich, es wie folgt zu handhaben:

> Die Bayerischen Motoren Werke (im Folgenden: BMW)

Somit gehst du sämtlichen Komplikationen aus dem Weg. Des Weiteren: Im Zweifelsfall würde ich immer diese Variante benutzen, denn, um wieder den Fachbereich Biologie anzusprechen, Akronyme wie AP (Aktionspotential) oder RP (Ruhepotential) sind nicht so weit verbreitet; hier wurde mir damals von meinem Tutor nahegelegt, es einmal mit dem zweiten Beispiel zu erläutern.

Comment: Das ganze hat einen winzigen Haken. Für mich ist die gängige Abkürzung BMW **der** BMW, weil es ein Auto beschreibt. Wenn ich vom Konzern rede, wäre die BMW AG eventuell die bessere Wahl. Das Problem besteht aber genau genommen auch schon in der Frage.

Comment: @Em1: *die BMW* ist in der Tat nicht gebräuchlich, *BMW* ohne Artikel (z.B. "Das Verkaufskonzept von BMW beruht auf ...") hingegen aber sehr, und es ist dann vollkommen klar, dass der Konzern gemeint ist.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper True. Ich bin halt nur über das "die BMW" gestolpert.